# sencha touch hello world program does not work

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I installed Sencha Touch 2 and wrote a simple hello world program. It displays Hello World on Chrome but without any mobile-like outfit. I checked and the style sheet file is accessible from the browser. What else could go wrong? Something is missing from the program?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <script src="../touch/sencha-touch-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            Ext.application({
                launch: function () {
                    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                        fullscreen: true,
                        html: 'Hello World!'
                    });
                }
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [Sencha CMD](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) and than create your app with this command:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sencha-touch-sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/www/myapp
```

This command will bootstrap your application structure with all the files you need. At the moment you're not able to see any styles because there is no app.json file (which will be created automatically), which refers to your app.css.

After that you still need XAMP or MAMP to run your application. If you don't have any of them installed, you can also use:

```
sencha fs web -p 8000 start -map /path/to/your/project
```

You find all of those infos in the [sencha documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/).

Comment: Thanks. At last I have found some examples that work, e.g. [this](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/first_app).

I put the code into a html skeleton that links to the sencha library and css installed. It works, but it does not have app/ and other directories that are created via the sencha command. What do I miss this way?

Comment: Did you use the 'generate app' command like explained over here: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/command_app ?